# Display dollar sign in php

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a snippet of code that outputs sales data. Is there a way to stick a dollar sign ($) in front of the outputted data?

The 'meta' line is the one that renders the numbers/data on the front end.

```
$orders = dokan_get_order_report_data( array(
    'data' => array(
        '_order_total' => array(
            'type'     => 'meta',
            'function' => 'SUM',
            'name'     => 'total_sales'
        ),
```

Comment: can't you concatenate a dollar sign on fronted of your application?

Comment: @Anant thank you. Can you show me how to change the code I posted above to reflect what you are saying? Where do I put the echo money_format statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any one of these:-

1.Use `money_format()` of php:-

```
echo money_format('%(#10n', $number) . "\n";
// ($        1,234.57)
```

Reference:- http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php

2.Use html codes for currency and concatenate it with your number.

Reference:- http://character-code.com/currency-html-codes.php

3.Direct concatenate `$` with your number value:-

```
<?php 
  $numbers = 10; 
  echo '$'.$numbers;
?>
```